# Flashbuilder Mobile PHP Data to SQLite sync

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

OK, I'm just hoping for pointers here please.

Within a mobile app I want to retrieve remote data using PHP, store it locally on my deveice and then sync it back to the remote server.

My methodology;

App opens
Checks for internet connection.
if available check for updated data, retrieve if necessary
if not available use local sqlite
When tasks complete
upload changes to remote server.

That's it

So far 
I can retrieve the remote data
Create a local SQLite db to mirrors the remote schema
check for connectivity

Where I am struggling is taking the PHP data and transferring it into the local sqlite, I used the flashbuilder wizard to create my data services and can see the data in the service.lastresult array, I just cant figure out how to transfer this array to the sqlite.

I'm currently going Google Crazy trying to search for anything that will help so any advice / pointers / critique would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have declared your RemoteObject:

```
<s:RemoteObject id="remoteObject" result="remoteObject_resultHandler(event)" />
```

Implemented the result handler

```
protected function remoteObject_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
    trace(event.result); // your response is here           
}
```

Now, each time your RemoteObject gets the response from the server remoteObject_resultHandler will be triggered.